# Phonegap: Getting a Canvas element to JPG for export?

Tags: ios, canvas, cordova, jpeg

We have an iOS app that uses canvas in PhoneGap. We can get the image out as a PNG, but what we're trying to do is get the canvas image out of PhoneGap as a JPG, as nearly all social sharing (Instagram, Facebook, etc.) prefer JPG.

This seems like a daunting task. Is it doable? I've spent some time searching and see the question asked here and there but no specific answer to the solution.

A more specific question, perhaps: What would you suggest for for getting an HTML5 Canvas object uploaded to a social photo sharing service (that provides an API for doing that) within PhoneGap?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know this PhoneGap, but the website says it's utilizing javascript and HTML5. If you are using Canvas.toDataURL method to get the PNG file. Well then try:

`Canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg");`

If iOS doesn't support that but you've managed to get `.png`:

Send it to a server and convert to any extension you want.

It looks like this library even have methods to make it easier:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: Yea, the server option is what we came up with, but is rather impractical from an iPhone app perspective (they'd need data connection, lag time, and just cost of running and maintaining a server). I'll look into the jpg formate toDataURL